# builtins.IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I have this function here:

```
def swap_cards(deck, index_deck):
    swap_deck = []
    after_index = []
    bandf_index = []
    if index_deck >= len(deck):
        for i in range(0, len(deck) + 1):
            if deck[i] == index_deck:
                after_index += [deck[0]]
            else:
                bandf_index += [deck[i]]
        swap_deck += [deck[index_deck]] + bandf_index[1:index_deck - 1] + after_index
```

Every time I try to input an index that is greater than or equal to the deck length I get the error 'list index out of range'

Example:

```
swap_cards([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 9)
```

I expect `[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]` but am instead getting 'list index out of range'.

Switching the last and the first number, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with len(). Assuming your index_deck is 9 as in the example above:

```
if index_deck >= len(deck):
    for i in range(0, len(deck) + 1):
```

This range will yield [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

```
        if deck[i] == index_deck:
            after_index += [deck[0]]
```

Since array indexes are zero-based, the above line will generate the error. deck[10] and deck[11] don't exist.

```
        else:
            bandf_index += [deck[i]]
```

Fixing the above `len()` statement will fix this as well (again, you may try to access deck[10] if the `if` statement is false.

```
    swap_deck += [deck[index_deck]] + bandf_index[1:index_deck - 1] + after_index
```

Final thing: you verify that `if index_deck >= len(deck):`. This will break the above line at `deck[index_check]` since here you will always access an index which does not exist.